# How to make a retrofit Post request to server with a String answer?

Tags: android, asp.net, retrofit

As descriped in my question I am using retrofit to make requests to my web service. My client is an Android App and my server is written in c# an api controller from an asp.net application. I managed to do post requests and send my data to the server but I somehow can´t manage to get an answer back.

My client:

```
public class RetrofitService implements TestRepository{

private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("http://my-host:22222")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();

private TestRepository testR = retrofit.create(TestRepository.class);

@Override 
public String saveTest(@Body Test test){return testR.saveTest(test);}

}

public interface TestRepository {
@POST("api/tests")
String saveTest(@Body Test test);
}
```

And this is how i call it:

```
RetrofitService service = new RetrofitService();
String answer = service.saveTest(test);
```

`Test` here is just a sample class.

My server:

```
public String Post([FromBody] Test test)
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

But everytime I run this I get an uncaughtExeption with no further explanation.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you know that you can't do network/internet tasks on the UI thread?
You are using a synchronous call maby it is better to use a asynchronous call with a callback handler:

```
public interface TestRepository {

@POST("api/tests")
void saveTest(@Body Test test, Callback<ModelObject> callback);

}
```

Then you can use an anonymous class to do some buisness logic:

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    /**
     * Model object test
     *      {
     *          "Code":"12345"
     *      }
     */
    Test test = new Test();


    new Thread(new TestTask(test, new Callback<ModelObject>() {

        @Override
        public void success(ModelObject mo, Response response) {
            Log.d("Test: ", mo.getAnswer());
            Log.d("Response: ", "" + response.getStatus());

            //OK = http response 200.
            if (response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.d("SomeClass: ", "MY RESPONSE WORKS :D");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("Error: ", error.toString());
        }

    })).start();
   }
}

public class TestTask implements Runnable {

    private RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://my-host:22222")
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();

    private final Test test;
    private final Callback<ModelObject> callback;

    public TestTask(final Test test, final Callback<ModelObject> callback) {
        this.test = test;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final TestRepository service = restAdapter.create(TestRepository.class);
        service.saveTest(test, callback);
    }
}
```

Also note that "String" as a callback type is a bit weird because Gson parses JSON body back to a model object. So the question is what does your backend gives back? A HTTP response or a JSON body.

```
   /**      Classic POJO class
     *      Json answer
     *      {
     *          "answer":"You got your answer"
     *      }
     *
     */
    public class ModelObject {

        private String answer;

        public String getAnswer() {
            return answer;
        }

        public void setAnswer(String answer) {
            this.answer = answer;
        }
    }
```